# Purpose of IDictionary interface

Tags: c#, .net, idictionary

What is the need of IDictionary interface. How can IDictionary interface be initialized. After all it is just an interface. The following code snippet is from msdn. I could not understand it.

```
IDictionary<string, string> openWith = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It defines the important [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) that an Dictionary should implement.

The line from MSDN means that you are creating an object *openWith* which implements the functions (methods) defined in **IDictionary** interface.

When you use Dictionary to declare the variable like:

```
Dictionary<string,string> openWith=.....;
```

you are bind with the concrete type of object. But when you use

```
IDictionary<string,string> openWith=....;
```

you can use it with any object that implements **IDictionary** *interface*, maybe your own custom class :)

Answer (score 10):

The whole point of interfaces is to provide... well, an interface to whatever module (I use "module" in a broad sense here) so that calling code will not have to worry about how this particular interface is implemented.

As for "How can `IDictionary` interface be initialized", this is technically not correct. What can be initialized is a variable, whose type is `IDictionary<T, V>`. Sure enough variables have to be initialized, but that's usually hidden from the "client code".

`IDictionary` is not very representative, however. Rather, consider an `IDataReader` interface. You've surely dealt with ADO.NET, so this should look familiar:

```
public Foo PopulateFromDataReader(SqlDataReader dataReader)
```

This particular method is tightly coupled to an `SqlDataReader`, so you'd have to rewrite it for it to support, say, Access or Oracle or MySQL or Firebird or whatever. In other words, you depend on implementation.

Now consider:

```
public Foo PopulateFromDataReader(IDataReader dataReader)
```

This method can be used with whatever class that implements `IDataReader`, which means with basically any ADO.NET-compatible data provider.

Comment: +1 Very nice example.. :) you cleared the diff which was making me confuse...  great example.

Answer (score 6):

It would be no different to any other interface. Try thinking about a simpler example:

```
interface IThermometer
{
    double CurrentTemperature { get; }
}
```

Now we have a way to get the temperature, though we don't care exactly how it's measured. We can create various implementations:

```
class MercuryThermometer : IThermometer
{
    public double CurrentTemperature
    {
        get { return ... /* gets the temperature somehow */ }
    }
}
```

The rest of the program doesn't need to know which thermometer it's using.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you've simply overlooked the difference between the variable typed as `IDictionary<,>` (the interface), and the value (reference) initialized as a `Dictionary<,>` (note no `I`; the concrete type).

Answer (score 2):

It's also useful for unit testing. You can write a unit test for a method that accepts an IDictionary instead of a Dictionary and pass a mock. If it were to accept a class instance (which could also be sealed) you'd be a little screwed (you'd have to use the adapter pattern and so on).